# Xcode 4.5 doesn't create some methods in viewController.m while creating a new class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new in programming, and I studied Xcode a bit (version 4.2). There, if you chose for example a new single view application, it would create correspondind viewController.m file with methods, like:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

and so on.
But now I have downloaded Xcode 4.5, created a new a new single view application, and in the corresponding viewController.m file there are only 3 methods:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
-(void)dealloc
```

and that's all. How can I add all that methods autommatically when a new viewController.m file is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are not added because they are deprecated in iOS6. Instead of using `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` you should override these:

`- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

As concerning viewDidLoad - views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me a link about this particular changes in methods and what methods should I use now instead of it?